# Insert in MySQL workbench, insert record a number of times

Tags: mysql

Say I have an insert like this:

```
Insert into table (id, date, quantity) 
Values(123, '2018-02-02', 5)
```

Which is fine, but I want that record to insert 5 times based on the quantity.
Alternatively, could I do the same with a select? So, select a record with an ID and date but if it has 5 as quantity, how could I select 5 copies of those?

Comment: But why????????!

Comment: Just a thought for the future. If you ever wanted to delete one of those records, or add another, does that mean you’ve got to update the quantity value for every single row with matching ID each time??

Comment: I have a cron running daily but I've been tasked with modifying it to pull 2 years worth of old data. Because of the loops and logic it's taking forever for all the old records. I already have all the records selected to insert but I need as many records for each one as it has set for quantity. I'm trying to do one batch insert to bypass the lengthy job

Comment: @brien good question, but no. It's simply a historical table

Comment: @TomN. OK, the alarms were going off. :-)

Comment: @brien I can understand! Haha. It's a weird request but we're devoting too much server time and memory to running this for old, inaccurate data. I just want to get it in there and move on

Comment: Ok, so loop on the value of quantity and do "quantity" inserts.

Comment: @Nic3500 how exactly do i do that though? I'm not familiar with loops or a procedure like this in MySQL.

Comment: Ya... my comment was not clear on that.  You loop in another language (ex. php or many others) then each loop sends 1 insert statement to MySQL.  I do not know the looping mechanisms offered by MySQL natively.  But someone does (look at the answer!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple rows having same entries **with different id** you need to create a procedure to do that .. try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(date DATE, quantity INT) 
   BEGIN SET @x = 0; 
      REPEAT 
         Insert into table ( date, quantity) Values(id, date, quantity );
         SET @x = @x + 1; 
         UNTIL @x >= quantity 
      END REPEAT; 
   END
```

and you can call it by using

```
CALL dorepeat(date ,quantity);
```